# MX Linux - can't shutdown/ reboot - /usr/bin/systemctl: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string

Tags: linux, shutdown, reboot, xfce, systemctl

Today i tried to install snapd, I found that it's not so easy on MX Linux as on different distributions. I found [this](https://mxlinux.org/wiki/applications/snap-packages-on-mx-17-sysvinit-this-doesnt-always-work/) (also [this](https://forum.mxlinux.org/viewtopic.php?t=44060) ) link where I had to add some script to my `/usr/bin/systemctl`. It didn't work so I deleted it, but when I tried to shutdown my pc, it didn't work. I tried it using a terminal and this is the error output:

```bsh
$ sudo systemctl reboot
/usr/bin/systemctl: 2: /usr/bin/systemctl: ELF: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 1: /usr/bin/systemctl: �: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 3: /usr/bin/systemctl: @8
                                             @@@@���������: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 4: /usr/bin/systemctl: �D: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 5: /usr/bin/systemctl: �D: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 1: /usr/bin/systemctl: s[g: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 1: /usr/bin/systemctl: �F��1: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 6: /usr/bin/systemctl: p���DD��
                                                   ��
                                                     ��
                                                      P�td��
                                                            ��
                                                              ��
                                                                ��Q�tdR�td��
                                                                            ��
                                                                              ��
                                                                                8p8p/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2GNUGNUE���ۦ��@R: not found
/usr/bin/systemctl: 5: /usr/bin/systemctl: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

I'm using laptop ASUS VivoBook S15 M533IA.

```bsh
$ uname -a
Linux tucna 5.9.0-16.1-liquorix-amd64 #1 ZEN SMP PREEMPT liquorix 5.9-16~mx19+1 (2020-12-27) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

**Thanks in advance! Any advice is welcome!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had completely messed the systemd files.

After a while I reinstalled the whole systemd using `sudo apt-get install --reinstall systemd` and **it fixed** the problem.

Maybe it will help someone.